# How do you paint vinyl shutters?

Tags: paint

What kind of paint will work for restoring the original color to vinyl shutters that have faded from exposure to the sun? They are supposedly "maintenance-free" but the home owners association says they need to be repaired or replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently repainted mine after aging 5 years.  They are maintenance free, but the color will fade.  Sherwin Williams sells paint specifically for shutters and they had an exact match for my shutter color.  You just wash and paint.  They'll look as good as new!